# Setting source for a script

Tags: webserver

I'm a bit confused as to how setting a source works for a script inside an HTML file.

Whenever I use a script, I set the source to something along the lines of:
http://localhost:8080/module_name/module.js

However, when I go through the directory of my server, the location is actually something along the lines of:
modules/module_version2.0/module_name/module.js

How is the client accessing the source file when portions of the directory are emitted?

Answer (score 1):

I think what is throwing you off is the configuration and root of the web-server/website versus the file system of the server.

The URL being read by your browser/client will lead the browser/client to the web-server located at localhost:8080 and the web-server will supply the browser/client with information from that website's root directory for any files/pages that are referenced within the html being used via the tags.

The method of configuring this direction/reference to the root or the document tree of the web-server, varies based on OS and web server setup, but is usually held in a files like httpd.conf; which is the file for Apache.

These configuration files can also have different file locations and aliases setup to create relative paths: i.e. you could have pointers for different locations within the web-server's document tree.

The path example from your server is coming from the perspective of a user account logged in to a machine using some method of exploring the systems local file structure. As such the root directory of that system is the lowest location in the file structure and therefore will show the full path of all the files and directories on that machine.

Where as the web-server/website's root directory in most likely located further away from the systems root.

Hope this helps.